# PHP/MYSQL Query returning reference ID instead of INT value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a php script with this statement:

```
$query = "SELECT type 
            FROM users 
           WHERE username = '$username'";

$result = $database->query($query);
if($result == 1) {
  echo "whatever";
  continue;
}
```

The problem is that the if never runs and when I created a print statement to print $result before the if runs, it prints a Reference ID#.  So result is never == 1 because it is being assigned the reference ID #.

What the heck am I doing wrong? How do I assign the value of 'type' which is an INT, instead of it's contents Reference ID#?

Comment: What is `$database` is it your own custom object, a`mysqli` connection, something else?

Comment: $database is an object used to open a connection to the database

Comment: Thank you all for your quick assistance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to fetch that line first ...

```
$query = "SELECT type FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = $database->query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row['type'] == 1)
{
      echo "whatever";
}
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error stating: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot break/continue 1 level

Comment: it's not my fault, I thought you got it in for or something like that. Answer edited ;)

Comment: hehe didn't mean to point fingers, I thought that continue was supposed to be there. I'm giving this a try, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use mysql_fetch_assoc() or mysql_fetch_array() to get the result into an array:

```
$query = $database->query("SELECT type FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if($result['type'] == 1)
{
    echo "whatever";
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<?php
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($database->query($query));
$id = $result['type'];
if($type == 1)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to check it like:

```
$query = "SELECT type FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = $database->query($query);
if($result)
{
    echo "whatever";
    continue;
}
```

This is a Boolean check, but... In php we have weak types - everything is true, except on **false**, **0**, **''** (empty string), null, etc.

If you want to make a good Boolean check including type, then you have:

```
if(bool_val === true)
{
..
}
// or
if(bool_val && is_bool(bool_val))
{
..
}
```

This query object returns a result resource in php. And you probably receive #Resource ID, which is some kind of pointer in php code.

If you receive something like this (#Resource ID) - this means your query has passed correctly and no error occured.